# How to deserialize the ByteArrays from C++ by reading from the file

Tags: java, c++, arrays, binaryfiles

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to write the `ByteArray` into the file. And afterwards, read that same file using the C++ program.

And the `ByteArray` that I am writing into the file is combination of these three `ByteArrays`-

- First **2 bytes** is my `schemaId` which I have represented it using short data type.
- Then next **8 Bytes** is my `Last Modified Date` which I have represented it using long data type.
- And remaining bytes can be of variable size which is my actual value for my attributes..

After writing resulting `ByteArray` into the file. Now I need to read that file from `C++ program` and read the first line which will contain the ByteArray and then split that resulting ByteArray accordingly as I mentioned above such that I am able to extract my `schemaId`, `Last Modified Date` and my actual `attribute value` from it.

I have done all my coding always in Java and I am new to C++... I am able to write a program in C++ to read the file but not sure how should I read that ByteArray in such a way such that I am able to split it as I mentioned above..

Below is my java code which will write resulting ByteArray into a file and the same file now I need to read it back from c++..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String os = "whatever os is";
    byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.getBytes();

    long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
    short schemaId = 32767;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOsTest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream outTest = new DataOutputStream(byteOsTest);
    outTest.writeShort(schemaId);
    outTest.writeLong(lastModifiedDate);
    outTest.writeInt(avroBinaryValue.length);
    outTest.write(avroBinaryValue);

    byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = byteOsTest.toByteArray();

    DataInputStream inTest = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allWrittenBytesTest));

    short schemaIdTest = inTest.readShort();

    long lastModifiedDateTest = inTest.readLong();

    int sizeAvroTest = inTest.readInt();
    byte[] avroBinaryValue1 = new byte[sizeAvroTest];
    inTest.read(avroBinaryValue1, 0, sizeAvroTest);


    System.out.println(schemaIdTest);
    System.out.println(lastModifiedDateTest);
    System.out.println(new String(avroBinaryValue1));

    writeFile(allWrittenBytesTest);
}

    /**
 * Write the file in Java
 * @param byteArray
 */
public static void writeFile(byte[] byteArray) {

    try{
        File file = new File("bytearrayfile");

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.write(byteArray, output);           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is my C++ program which is reading the above file (written by Java) and I am not sure what I am supposed to do to split the ByteArrays in such a way so that I can read individual ByteArrays accordingly..

```
#include "ReadFile.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;

    std::ifstream myfile("bytearrayfile", std::ios::binary);

    //check to see if the file is opened:
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        //while there are still lines in the
        //file, keep reading:
        while (! myfile.eof() )
        {

        // I am not sure what I am supposed to do here?

        }

        //close the stream:
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

After deserializing the individual ByteArray, I should be able to extract schemaId as `32767`, `lastModifiedDate` as `1379811105109` and my Attribute value as `whatever os is` from the above C++ program.

I am new to C++ so facing lot of problems on it. Any example basis on my code will help me to understand better.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

**Updated:-**

Below is my latest code by which I am able to extract `schemaId`, `lastModifiedDate` and `attributeLength`.

But not sure how to extract the actual Attribute Value-

```
int main() {
    string line;

    std::ifstream myfile("bytearrayfile", std::ios::binary);

    if (myfile.is_open()) {

        uint16_t schemaId;
        uint64_t lastModifiedDate;
        uint32_t attributeLength;

        char buffer[8]; // sized for the biggest read we want to do

        // read two bytes (will be in the wrong order)
        myfile.read(buffer, 2);
        // swap the bytes
        std::swap(buffer[0], buffer[1]);

        // only now convert bytes to an integer
        schemaId = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(buffer);

        cout<< schemaId <<endl;

        // read eight bytes (will be in the wrong order)
        myfile.read(buffer, 8);
        // swap the bytes
        std::swap(buffer[0], buffer[7]);
        std::swap(buffer[1], buffer[6]);
        std::swap(buffer[2], buffer[5]);
        std::swap(buffer[3], buffer[4]);

        // only now convert bytes to an integer
        lastModifiedDate = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(buffer);

        cout<< lastModifiedDate <<endl;

        // read 4 bytes (will be in the wrong order)
        myfile.read(buffer, 4);
        // swap the bytes
        std::swap(buffer[0], buffer[3]);
        std::swap(buffer[1], buffer[2]);

        // only now convert bytes to an integer
        attributeLength = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(buffer);

        cout<< attributeLength <<endl;

      // not sure how to extract the actual attribute value?

        //close the stream:
        myfile.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you got `while (! myfile.eof() )`? Think about what you are doing. You have to read the same things in C++ that you wrote in Java. In Java there are four things written, so in C++ you read the same four things back. There's no loop until the end of file needed.

Comment: Can you specify other format for serialization? For example [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [BSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON)? See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser

Comment: @john: I got that while loop as I was following some tutorial on C++ on how to read the file in C++ code.. I am not that good in C++ so that's why I am facing some problem on this..

Comment: @yegorich: I am not using JSON or will be using JSON for some reason in my project.. I will be using the memory solution I believe in my use case..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T That tutorial you read reading was for reading lines from a text file (just look at the comments), you are reading binary data which is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java your program is

1. write schema id
2. write last modifed date
3. write avro binary data length
4. write avro binary data

So in C++ your program is

1. read schema id
2. read last modified date
3. read avro binary data length
4. read avro binary data

There's really very little difference between C++ and Java for this program, so if you can do it in Java you should (with a little research) be able to do it in C++.

Here's a start (item 1)

```
short schemaId;
myFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&schemaId), sizeof(short));
```

`reinterpret_cast<char*>` is necessary because the read function needs a `char*` for it's first argument. So if the first argument is anything other than a pointer to char a cast is necessary.

This does assume that `sizeof(short) == 2` (always true in Java, usually true in C++), and that there are no endianess issues. Hard to know about this, you'll just have to try it and see.

It is possible that your implementation of Java and C++ will use a different byte order when reading or writing binary integers. This is called *endianess*. If that's the case then you will have to swap the byte order when you read integers. Here's some code to do this (it's pretty tedious stuff and there may be a cleaner way).

```
uint16_t schemaId;
uint64_t lastModifiedDate;
uint32_t attributeLength;
char buffer[8]; // sized for the biggest read we want to do

// read two bytes (will be in the wrong order)
myfile.read(buffer, 2);
// swap the bytes
std::swap(buffer[0], buffer[1]);
// only now convert bytes to an integer
schemaId = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(buffer);

// read eight bytes (will be in the wrong order)
myfile.read(buffer, 8);
// swap the bytes
std::swap(buffer[0], buffer[7]);
std::swap(buffer[1], buffer[6]);
std::swap(buffer[2], buffer[5]);
std::swap(buffer[3], buffer[4]);
// only now convert bytes to an integer
lastModifiedDate = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(buffer);
```

etc...

You need to `#include <algorithm>` to get the `std::swap` function.

Comment: Thanks John.. If I am doing it for the first one like this - `short schemaId;
myfile.read((&schemaId), sizeof(short));` I always get this error `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read(short int*, unsigned int)'` Not sure why?

Comment: Thanks John, that error is gone now.. But I am getting very different result for schemaId. I have updated my question with the actual code..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T That's an *endianess* issue, are you familar with that concept? Basically the problem is that Java and your implementation of C++ are using different formats for binary I/O of integers. That complicates things.

Comment: no I am not.. :( I updated question again with very strange issue.. If I am using different datatype, I am getting different result..

Comment: In my java program, I am using short for `schemaId` that's all... And which is my starting two bytes in my resulting bytearray.. So there should be something in c++ which will be able to decode that.. right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38375/discussion-between-trekkietechie-t-t-and-john)

Comment: I have posted my latest code in my question. I have fixed all the problems and now I am able to extract schemaId, lastModifiedDate and attributeLength but not able to extract actual attribute value.. Not sure how to do that as well.